# Pixels to percentages media query troubleshoot?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pixel

I am trying to convert all my pixels on my style sheet to percentages in order to set up a media query for @media only screen and (max-width: 600px). Most of the elements on the page work, however I have a specific section where each image is in a div container of its own, which is then inserted in another div container, then three of these images are wrapped in another div container in order to form a row of three images.

Here is an example:

```
 <div class="rowOne">

        <div class="imagewrapper">
            <div id="strawberry"></div>
        </div>    

        <div class="imagewrapper">
            <div id="mango"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="imagewrapper">
            <div id="watermelon"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Afterwards, all of these rows are overall contained in a . In my css, I have attempted to change the pixels to percentages on the width of the strawberry and it seems that it seems somewhat responsive.

```
#strawberry {
    width: 72%;
    height: 308px;
    background: url('../images/strawberry.png') 0 0;

}

#strawberry:hover {
    width: 73%;
    height: 308px;
    background: url(../images/strawberrysprite.png) 0 0;
}


#mango {
    width: 315px;
    height: 264px;
    background: url('../images/mango.png') 0 0;

}

#mango:hover {
    width: 315px;
    height: 264px;
    background: url(../images/mangosprite.png) 0 0;
}

#watermelon {
    width: 272px;
    height: 380px;
    background: url('../images/watermelon.png') 0 0;
}

#watermelon:hover {
    width: 272px;
    height: 380px;
    background: url(../images/watermelonsprite.png) 0 0;
}
```

When I change the height to percentages however, the entire image disappears and regardless of whatever the input it does not seem to make a difference. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Here is a link to the published website.](https://xarts.usfca.edu/~jyang67/rootfolder2/)

Comment: Try adding a height to its container, then use percentage in the container for the images

Comment: Why not set the images to 100% and let their containers do the rest rather than specifically controlling their widths and heights?